# Create random element from group G in BLS Scheme

Tags: elliptic-curves, group-theory, bls-signature

I hope this question is not too basic. I'm currently trying to implement compact proofs of retrievability that are publicly verifiable by BLS scheme as described in this paper [Compact Proofs of Retrievability](https://eprint.iacr.org/2008/073.pdf) in GO. I already implemented it with RSA and now I want to do the same with the BLS Scheme as described in section 3.3 on page 12. For simplicity it is symmetric.

It states that I should generate $s$ random elements: $ u_1 ... u_s \overset{{R}}{\leftarrow} G$ and this is where I'm not quiet sure how to interpret this.

Would it be sufficient to generate random numbers $x_1 ... x_s$ from $\mathbb{Z_p}$ (private key is derived from $\mathbb{Z_p}$) and use a generator $g$ of $G$ to calculate $u_s \leftarrow g^{x_s}$ for example? Or am I on the completely wrong track there?

Thanks and regards.

Comment: This should work since $G$ is cyclic and has order $p$ (and therefore $G$ and $\mathbb{Z}_p$ are isomorphic).

Comment: Would it be also sufficient enough to just generate the random numbers $x_1...x_2$ from $\mathbb{Z}_p$ if they are of the same order as $G$? So there would be no need to do $u_s \leftarrow g^{x_s}$.

Comment: That does not work since the elements of $\mathbb{Z}_p$ and $G$ might look different (e.g., in the case where $G$ is defined using elliptic curves), and the way to "translate" from $\mathbb{Z}_p$ to $G$ is using the map $x\mapsto g^x$, where $g$ is a generator of $G$.

Comment: Okay so let $e: G_1 \times G_1 \rightarrow G_T$ be a bilinear map. $G_1$ is a BN256 (alt_bn128) elliptic curve. Now if i choose  $u_1 ... u_s \overset{{R}}{\leftarrow} G_1$ every single $u$ will be a generator of $G_1$, right? Because if they are, I don't know i can compute the following, as stated in the paper: $\prod_{j=1}^s u_j$ because we would need to multiply the points, and multiplication of multiple points is not defined for elliptic curves. Or could the $\prod$ in this case simply be interpreted as a $\Sigma$ as we are working on curves?

Comment: Yes, they are using the multiplicative notation for groups (instead of the additive notation). You can simply substitute the exponentiations with scalar multiplications and products with addition.